# MQTTnet PublishAsync Exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, mqtt

I'm trying to use "MQTTnet" in a Xamarin application. It connects fine but when I try to publish anything, well, it publishs but after about 5 seconds it throw the following exception

```
MQTTnet.Exceptions.MqttCommunicationTimedOutException
```

I'm not quite sure about what's happening there, the message is received successfully by the server

```
Server auth xmr/47cd7021-0f32-4cd4-b549-e8ebce2df612 from 192.168.1.8
Client xmr/47cd7021-0f32-4cd4-b549-e8ebce2df612 connected
Total connections: 3
$SYS/POezxDu/new/clients xmr/47cd7021-0f32-4cd4-b549-e8ebce2df612
hello/world hey
Client xmr/47cd7021-0f32-4cd4-b549-e8ebce2df612 disconnected
Total connections: 2
$SYS/POezxDu/disconnect/clients xmr/47cd7021-0f32-4cd4-b549-e8ebce2df612
```

Below is the code:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using MQTTnet;
using MQTTnet.Client;
using MQTTnet.Client.Options;
using System.Threading;

namespace MQTTXamarin
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Login : ContentPage
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Btn_Login_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MqttConnect();  
        }

        /* MQTT */
        readonly IMqttClient client = new MqttFactory().CreateMqttClient();
        private async void MqttConnect()
        {
            var options = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                .WithClientId("xmr/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                .WithTcpServer("192.168.1.200", 1883)
                .WithCredentials("DyPFunIOcljUT51i", "K1YMeKkvrK6yMvm7IlHadBA6JDBKzPGc")
                .Build();
            await client.ConnectAsync(options, CancellationToken.None);
            var message = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
                .WithTopic("hello/world")
                .WithPayload("hey")
                .WithExactlyOnceQoS()
                .Build();
            await client.PublishAsync(message, CancellationToken.None);
        }

    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this buggy?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it. 
Which broker are you using? Which MQTT version is the broker using?
If you need to use a certain version in your application, use the `.WithProtocolVersion(...)` add-on when building the `options`. (5.0 is the latest & greatest.)

Since you get a timeout it seems that the client doesn't get some expected feedback. Try to reduce the QoS (to the minimum to start with; `WithAtMostOnceQoS()` instead of 'ExactlyOnce').

Comment: Reducing the QoS worked very well. WithAtLeastOnceQoS() working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved changing the

```
.WithExactlyOnceQoS()
```

to

```
.WithAtLeastOnceQoS()
```